# C array indexing in MIPS assembly?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, mips

Question:

```
void swap (int v[], int k)
{
int temp;
temp = v[k];
v[k] = v[k+1];
v[k+1] = temp;
}
```

My question is why does int `v[]` get added `$t1`? (whoever did this didn't even comment it so I'm assuming `$a0` is`v[]` and `$a1` is `k`).

Answer in mips:

```
swap: sll $t1, $a1, 2
add $t1, $a0, $t1
lw $t0, 0($t1)
lw $t2, 4($t1)
sw $t2, 0($t1)
sw $t0, 4($t1)
jr $ra
```

I know this is used to swap variables but what is it doing here, why is it adding `v[]` with `k`? Isn't `v[]` a array of declared variables, how can you add it with a integer `k`?

Comment: Where is that while loop which you mention in the title? I do not see it.

Comment: You should look up the calling convention being used to see how arguments are passed instead of just guessing.

Comment: Have you verified that the assembler code by unknown author does the same as the  c/C++ code? Which of the languages is it by the way?

Comment: You seem to be unclear about meaning, useage, implementation and handling of arrays in the language of your choice. Doing some tutorials on that topic in that language (not assembler) would probably set you up with a better foundation for this question. It for example help you understanding where the adding of index and "the array" is coming in.

Answer (score 1):

> whoever did this didn't even comment it so I'm assuming $a0 is v[] and $a1 is k

These are the MIPS [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#MIPS). First 4 arguments of a function are in `$a0..$a3` and return value (not required here) is in `$v0` (and `$v1` if required). Return address is in register `$ra`.

> I know this is used to swap variables but what is it doing here, why is it adding v[] with k? isnt v[] a array of declared variables, how can you add it with a integer k?

v[] is indeed an array of int. What holds variable v is the address of the array. Adding a value to an array address is the way to go to specific elements of the array.

```
swap:                   # void swap (int v[], int k)
                        ; so v[] is in $a0 and k in $a1
      sll $t1, $a1, 2   ; k*=4 (ie sizeof(int))
      add $t1, $a0, $t1 ; $t1=@v+4*k==@(v[k])
      lw $t0, 0($t1)    #   temp = v[k];
      lw $t2, 4($t1)    ; 4(t1) is @(v[k])+4==@(v[k+1]
                        ; $t0==temp==v[k], $t2==v[k+1]
      sw $t2, 0($t1)    #   v[k] = v[k+1]; 
      sw $t0, 4($t1)    #   v[k+1] = temp;
      jr $ra            ; go back to caller
```